# Quick Look Preview of html files not working after iOS 13 upgrade in iPad

Tags: ipad, preview, quicklook, ios, quicklook-plugin

After updating to iOS X 13, I can no longer use Quick Look on HTML files available in mail – I just get a blank preview window or enable javascript window, and the issue persists through a reboot. But all other files types work fine.

Is there a cache I can clear or something else I can try to get this working again?

Comment: *Note:* Its working fine in previous OS which is iOS 12,.but after updating to recent upgrade we are facing issues

Answer (score 1):

Apple has disabled JavaScript in Quick Look for security/privacy reasons (this was used to track users previewing local files by pinging remote servers).

If you have your own app, use a WKWebView if you need JavaScript execution. If you are sending HTML content with JavaScript via email, send a link to a remote server instead. With a link people know they are contacting a remote server.

Comment: Yes, currently we are sending HTML content with Javascript via e-mail. Can you please let me know what exactly you meant by sending a link to remote server instead?

Comment: Actually I am not sure on iPad and iOS. We are using our html files to be viewed in iPad from e-mail using quicklook and from iOS upgrade, we are not able to view them.  We don't have any mobile app as well. Please suggest any alternative for this

Comment: Can you host your content on a Web server and send a link to it instead of attaching an HTML file? Or send an HTML file which does not need JavaScript.

Comment: No, we want to send HTML file through e-mail only as our users mainly need them for offline view even without network. Hence hosting on webserver may not work and our HTML file comprises of jQuery and Javascript only

Comment: Then tell users to open the share sheet and open the file in Safari? I don’t think this is possible anymore in Quick Look directly for security reasons, you’re going to need to find a different way to deliver your content if you do need JS.

Comment: Any chance to get the option to open the file in safari - because I have option icon and when I click I don't see an option to open the file in safari or any browser from e-mail?

I can ask users to select that option and open in any browser ..Please suggest

Comment: I dont see any option to open file in any browser in share sheet

Comment: You should file a bug if that option is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have raised a bug in feedback assistant about quicklook javascript disable issue.Can you please let me know if there is any other site to raise a bug to apple

Comment: No, feedback assistant is the way to go.